# Pyspark: multiplying columns from different tables

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I have these two dataframes:

```
df1 = sc.parallelize([
['u1', 0.5],
['u2', 0.2],
['u3', 0.1],
['u4', 0.9],
['u5', 0.7]
]).toDF(('person', 'score'))

df2 = sc.parallelize([
['d1', 0.0],
['d2', 0.5],
['d3', 0.7],
]).toDF(('dog', 'score'))
```

What I need to do is creating another dataframe whose schema would be

> person, dog, score_person * score_dog

so basically multiplying the column `score` in both dataframes and keeping the two first columns. This multiplication has to take place for each possible couple of factors, i.e. each person with each dog, so that my result dataframe would have 15 rows.

I can't find a way to obtain this, it seems to me that it has to pass through a SELECT on both dataframes but no JOIN nor UNION can help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically Cartesian product is something you want to avoid but simple `join` without `on` parameter is all you need here:

```
df1.join(df2).select("person", "dog", (df1.score * df2.score).alias("product"))
```

Comment: Looks grand, any reason why I get things like this though: Row(person=u'u1', dog=u'd2', product=None) (the None)? There are several in the result and some other ones are 0. Is it a problem with types?

Comment: It is. `type(0)` (the part I've corrected) is `int`, while `type (0.5)` is `float`. Spark `DataFrame` can contain only single type (the first value is taken to determine schema) and all other values will be discarded. You can check it happens before `join`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this question is a few years old but found an explicit Cross Join method added in version 2.1. Try:

```
df1.crossJoin(df2).select("person", "dog", (df1.score * df2.score).alias("product"))
```

found information here: http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.crossJoin